# How can I reproduce what the UI does when enabling CORS in the API Gateway using the AWS CLI

Tags: aws-cli, api-gateway

When defining an API through the UI, I can simply select the "Enable CORS" option and it adds OPTIONS methods and a number of header mappings.

How can I achieve this through the command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable CORS in AWS API Gateway with aws-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617182/enable-cors-in-aws-api-gateway-with-aws-cli)

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725722/updating-cors-policy-of-http-api-via-aws-cli